# Why is MySQL transaction lock only blocking other locks?

Tags: mysql, locking

I'm trying to understand database locking and have come around a strange thing.

I am running MySQL version 5.7.24.

In the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docs` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `docs` (`id`, `content`) VALUES
  ('1', 'The earth is flat'),
  ('2', 'One hundred angels can dance on the head of a pin'),
  ('3', 'The earth is flat and rests on a bull\'s horn'),
  ('4', 'The earth is like a ball.');
```

*[Example 1]:*

In **connection A**:

```
BEGIN;
select * from docs where id = 2 FOR UPDATE;
```

And then in **connection B**:

```
select * from docs where id = 2 FOR UPDATE;
```

Connection B waits for the transaction in connection A to be committed.
That is what I would expect.

*[Example 2]:*

In **connection A**:

```
BEGIN;
select * from docs where id = 2 FOR UPDATE;
```

And then in **connection B**:

```
select * from docs where id = 2;
```

Then I get the result immediately in connection B.
Why doesn't it wait for the transaction in connection A to be committed?

The same happens if I instead of a SELECT statement would do an UPDATE - in which case there would be a "lost update" and I would think that the lock created in connection A would prevent that.

Does I have to run all queries as locks (FOR UPDATE) even if they only selects data from the table.

Best regards thephper :-)

Comment: Read [and then re-read](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking.html)

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly . I stated in the question that "The same happens if I instead of a SELECT statement would do an UPDATE", but I can now see that this is in fact not true.

Per the docs:
"A record lock is a lock on an index record. For example, SELECT c1 FROM t WHERE c1 = 10 FOR UPDATE; prevents any other transaction from inserting, updating, or deleting rows where the value of t.c1 is 10."

Maybe you can place an answer, so that I can mark it as resolved?